# Classes, variables and everything else ,actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, performance

Im making a game that was built from 3 classes right now.
1st is the main document,
the player,
and the enemy.
My question is, how do I interacte between the player and the enemy classes.
for example, how do I call from the player class a function from the enemy class?
or how do I change the enemy class's variable value from the player class?
is there a general name to it so i can learn it myself?

Im quite new to actionscript 3 (2 months expirience) and Im designing my 3'd game right now.
Somehow i managed to get by. making lots of non effective functions in the document class which made my code exetremly long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a new static class (in addition to the classes you've built)

**InteractionManager**

that stores the reference to the enemy and the player

```
package {

    public class InteractionManager {

        public static var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
        public static var player:Player = new Player();


        [special interaction methods besides the player and enemy methods]  
        .  
        .  
        .  

     }  
}
```

**the player can call**

```
InteractionManager.enemy.method();
```

**and the enemy can call**

```
InteractionManager.player.method();
```

Comment: It works perfect!!! thank you!!
But now that it works I have no idea why?
Why is this class diffrent from the document class?
If i type in the player class 'MainDocument.enemy.method();'
it says acsess of undefind property of a refrence with static type class.

Comment: I guess because enemy is a child of MainDocument, So you need to getChild (not sure that "getChildByName" will work for you). But InteractionManager holds a reference to enemy.. You can do the same thing in MainDocument. just copy "public static var enemy......" to the right place and there you go... Good Luck!!